# jquery mouse-over making the DIVs go crazy when hovering over multiple links

Tags: jquery, html, css

Good morning

see my js http://jsfiddle.net/LEyFW/

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {

    $(".mark").bind("mouseover", function () {
        var DivId = $(this).attr("href");
        $('.icontent').hide();
        $(DivId).fadeIn(300);
    });
    $(".mark").bind("mouseout", function () {
        $('.icontent').hide();
        $("#defaultdiv").fadeIn(300);
    });
});

    </script>


<style>


ul {



    padding:0px 0px 0px 30px;

}

ul > li {

    color: #dc3fb0;

}

ul > li > span {

    color: #58595b;

}

.title {

    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;

    font-size: 18px;

    color: #58595b;

    border-bottom: solid 2px #666666;

    padding-left: 15px;

    padding-top:5px;

}

#Contenair {

    border: solid 2px #666666;

    height:246px;

    width:500px;

}

icontent {
    width: 454px;
    height: 246px;


    }

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    }


</style>


</head>

<body bgcolor="#e3e3e3">
<div style="height:490px; width:454px;">
<table style="background-color: #FFF;" width="454" height="460" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-image:url(public-finance-bg.jpg); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position-x: 4px;
background-position-y: 20px; font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 17px; color: #58595b; height: 300px;">
            <div class="icontent" id="defaultdiv">
                 <div style="padding-top: 10px;
height: 70px; padding-left: 9px;">Network Rail ordered to pay back 
£53m over late trains</div>
                <img src="train.jpg" width="454" height="246" />
            </div>
            <div class="icontent" style="display: none" id="cont1">
                 <div style="padding-top: 10px;
height: 70px; padding-left: 9px;">Public Finance random news</div>
                <img src="plane.jpg" width="454" height="246" />
            </div>
            <div class="icontent"  style="display: none" id="cont2">
                 <div style="padding-top: 10px;
height: 70px; padding-left: 9px;">Better Care Fund cash 'could finance hospitals</div>
                <img src="bus.jpg" width="454" height="246" />
            </div>

             <div class="icontent"  style="display: none" id="cont3">
                 <div style="padding-top: 10px;
height: 70px; padding-left: 9px;">Ministers sign 'single pot' growth deals</div>
                <img src="car.jpg" width="454" height="246" />
            </div>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="height: 27px;">
        <td style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #58595b; border-bottom: solid 2px #666666; padding-left: 15px; padding-top: 12px;">Latest News</td>
    </tr>


    <tr style="height: 35px;">
        <td height="22" valign="top" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #58595b;">
           <ul>
<li><a href="#cont1" class="mark" id="mark1"><span style="color: #666;">Better Care Fund cash could finance hospitals</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr style="height: 35px;">
        <td height="22" valign="top" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #58595b;">
           <ul>
                <li><a href="#cont2" class="mark" id="mark2"><span style="color: #666;">Better Care Fund cash could finance hospitals</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr style="height: 35px;">
        <td valign="top" style="font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; color: #58595b;">
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#cont3" class="mark" id="mark3"><span style="color: #666;">Better Care Fund cash could finance hospitals</span></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a mouse-over for showing different div content in the same box.

Works but - try hovering over all of the links very quickly and you will see what happens. Multiple divs start showing up and it gets stuck.

Any way to calm it down?

Comment: Does my answer solves your problem?

Comment: @user3168736 Yes, as per the question. Your answer will be the correct one. Voted.

Answer (score 4):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/LEyFW/1/)

```
stop(true)
```

Try this. It will not cause to clause multiple animations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LEyFW/2/)

```
$(function () {
   $('.icontent').hide();
   $('.icontent').eq(0).show();
   $(".mark").bind("mouseover", function () {
    var DivId = $(this).attr("href");
    $('.icontent').hide();
    $(DivId).stop().fadeIn(300);
   });
   $(".mark").bind("mouseout", function () {
    $('.icontent').hide();
    $("#defaultdiv").fadeIn(300);
   });
 });
```